# .Net4, Monitor.Enter(lockObject, acquiredLock)

Tags: .net, locking, thread-safety

In .Net4, [Monitor.Enter(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz(VS.100).aspx) is marked as obsolete :

```
[ObsoleteAttribute("This method does not allow its caller to reliably release the lock.  Please use an overload with a lockTaken argument instead.")]
public static void Enter(
    Object obj
)
```

And there is a new method [Monitor.Enter(lockObject, acquiredLock)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498(VS.100).aspx) with this usage :

```
bool acquiredLock = false;

try
{
    Monitor.Enter(lockObject, ref acquiredLock);

    // Code that accesses resources that are protected by the lock.

}
finally
{
    if (acquiredLock)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
}
```

I used to do it this way :

```
Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
try
{

    // Code that accesses resources that are protected by the lock.
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
}
```

Is it wrong ? Why ?
Maybe with an interupt after the enter but before the try ?
**As Eamon Nerbonne asked : what happens if there's an async exception in the finally right before monitor.exit?**

Answer : [ThreadAbortException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx)

> When this exception is raised, the
>   runtime executes all the finally
>   blocks before ending the thread.

Comment: What happens if there's an async exception in the finally right before monitor.exit?

Comment: I don't know about other asynchronous exceptions, but the CLR prevents abort exceptions from interrupting finally blocks - and other asynchronous exceptions are more likely to take down the process anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you suggest right at the end of the question, the problem is that an [asynchronous exception](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2009/03/13/ManagedCodeAndAsynchronousExceptionHardening.aspx) could be thrown after the call to `Monitor.Enter` but before you enter the `try` block.

The new way of doing things makes sure that whatever happens, you'll hit the finally block and be able to release the lock *if* you acquired it. (You may not acquire it if `Monitor.Enter` throws an exception, for example.)

IIRC, this is the new behaviour of the `lock` keyword when targeting .NET 4.0.

Comment: Yup, lock has been changed to use the new construct (or at least it was in beta1)

Comment: I will accept the answer if you can answer to Eamon Nerbonne question ;)